# Data extension name changes reflected in Attribute Group?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We made a change to the names of 2 data extensions that we have been using in a journey. Basically, from JourneyAudience_2019 --> JourneyAudience_2020, and Master_Data_2019 --> Master_Data_2020. The former is used as the journey's entry source, while the latter is used for comparison, via the contact model/data.  Now, I saw that this small change was immediatelly reflected in the Attribute Group, while Journey Builder prompted me with a message to re-map the compared data, which I did in the Journey Splits. The test showed everything was fine, but now I'm wondering will the real journey be OK as well. So the question here is whether the change of the DEs names would affect the corresponding Attribute Group?